# how can i disable gray shape beside cursor on illustrator cc 2019?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

when working on the illustrator document
this cursor(gray) shape is always emerged

how can i disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to that thick grey line, extending from the toolbar to the artboard, that would appear to be an issue with the display, or RAM possibly. Or perhaps a bad installation. **It's not standard.**

You might try toggling the **CPU/GPU preview** in the **View Menu** to see if it addresses the issue. If it does, the grey line may be due to some incompatibility or problem with your video card.

Beyond that, you'll need to contact Adobe because it's clearly a technical issue if it appears on all Illustrator documents you open.

Comment: thank you. I will refer to your answer. thanks to you, i have nice advice